# How to solve this Complex Integration?

Tags: integration

> Question 4.
>   Calculate 
>   $$\oint_\gamma\frac{\bar z}{z-2}\,dz, $$
>   where $\gamma$ is the circle $|z-2| = 2$, with positive orientation.

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6OeZ.png)

We're yet not seeing residues. My guess is that I have to parametrize the curve and set integration limits to solve it, but I don't know how to proceed with |z-2|=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Set $z(t)=2 + 2 e^{it}$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$. The integral then becomes:
  $$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2+2^{-it}} {2 e^{it}} 2 i e^{it} dt $$

Comment: I can see where we're going, but still don't know which limits should I define.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was looking at some note classes and apparently we put z(t) on f(z) and multiply by z'(t) and then solve the integral. Thanks! (still not as simple as I though, but now it's done c:)

Comment: It's pretty much just a u-substitution. z gets replaced with t, and dz is replaced with z'(t) dt. That's where the multiplication with z'(t) comes from.